# How to append errors to a class using the 'ActiveModel::Errors' module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, activemodel

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to exend a class Account in order [to handle errors "a la Rails way"](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb).

In my model I have

```
class Users::Account
  extend  ActiveModel::Naming
  extend  ActiveModel::Translation
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  attr_reader :errors

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)

    @firstname = attributes[:firstname]
    @lastname = attributes[:lastname]
    ...
  end
end
```

I would like to "encapsulate" in the above class the following hash using the `ActiveModel::Errors`

```
--- 
errors: 
  base: Invalid account.
  firstname: Too short.
```

so that I can do, after inserting the above error hash in the class, like this

```
@account.errors # => Hash of errors
```

A debug for a testing scenario is (always) the following because I don't know how to append errors to the class.

```
firstname: T
lastname: Test surname
errors: !omap []
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can actually just do

```
somemodel_instance.errors.add(:some_attr, "some error message")
```

for more info, refer to [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#working-with-validation-errors), hope this helps =)

Comment: if that's the case, probably hash isn't a good way of doing it isn't it? or if you insist on using hash, prob u'll have to structure it along the line of {:attr_1 => "message 1", :attr_2 => "message 2"}